# C++ error "invalid constructor; your probably meant 'Account (const Account&)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I keep getting the error

> invalid constructor; your probably meant `Account (const Account&)`.

```
explicit Account (Account balance) {
   : accountBalance (balance);
}
```

I've tried changing the input to be `(Account balance)` and tried also using `(int balance)`. int balance gives me an error

> "expected primary-expression before ':' token.

Full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Account {
public:

    explicit Account (Account balance) {
       : accountBalance (balance);
    }

    void setAccountBalance (int balance) {
        accountBalance = balance;
    }

    int getAccountBalance () const {
        return accountBalance;
    }

    void displayBalance () const {
        std::cout << "Welcome to the Account. The balance is : $" << getAccountBalance() << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int accountBalance;
};

int main () {
    int startBalance = 0;
    Account myAccount1;

    cout << "Initial Dollar Amount is : " << myAccount1.getAccountBalance() << endl;
    cout << "Please enter new balance : " << endl;
    cin >> startBalance;

    myAccount1.setAccountBalance(startBalance);
    myAccount1.displayBalance();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to fix your constructor and the initialization list, as follows

```
explicit Account (int balance):accountBalance (balance){}
```

you need to provide an argument when creating `Account` object, as follows

```
int startBalance = 0;
Account myAccount1(startBalance);
```

Comment: Ahh yes thank you. I see now that I put 

: accountBalance (balance);

Within the function of explicit Account (int balance). And I also put a semi-colon at the end. ^.^ Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Greg you welcome ! .. you might accept one of the answers to your question .. for more info http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
Account (Account balance)
```

with

```
Account (int balance) 
//       ^^^
```

Comment: int balance gives me an error of "expected primary-expression before ':' token.